# Issue with testing async class method with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs

I have a class that has an async constructor called init(). I am trying to create a test for it, but I am having some issues. The code works fine, but the tests gives the following error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout
>   specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked
>   within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

This is the class:

```
const { Settings } = require("../models/settings");
const moment = require("moment");

class Config {

  async init() {

    let settings = await Settings.findOne(); // This looks like the line where it gets stuck
    if (!settings) settings = await createDefaultConfig();

    this.lastBookableDay = settings.lastBookableDay;
    this.slotDuration = settings.slotDuration;
    this.interval = settings.interval;
    this.expireOffset = settings.expireOffset;
    this.cancelationNotice = settings.cancelationNotice;
    this.week = settings.week;
  }
}

async function createDefaultConfig() {
  const settings = await Settings.find();
  let last = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  last = moment(last).add(10, "day").unix();
  if (settings.length < 1) {
    const newSettings = new Settings({
      lastBookableDay: last,
      slotDuration: 50,
      interval: 10,
      expireOffset: 60,
      cancelationNotice: 24,
      week: [...new Array(7)].map(() =>
        ({ startHours: 10, startMinutes: 0, slotNumber: 5, off: false }))
    });
    await newSettings.save();
  }
}

module.exports = Config;
```

I have other tests that access the db with no issues.

This is the code of the failing test (for simplicity there is no cleanup of the db):

```
const Settings = require("./settings.js");

describe("Settings class", () => {

  it("should init settings instance", async () => {

    const settings = new Settings();
    await settings.init();

    console.log(settings)
    expect(settings.slotDuration).toBe(50);
  })

});
```

Can someone point me out what I'm doing wrong please? Thanks.

Comment: 1. The tag for jest is [tag:jestjs] 2. this looks like mocha 3. the docs state to use done: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Nope, I don't even have mocha in my dependencies.

Comment: I guess it's installed globally then. jest uses the `test()` command, and googling for `js test describe` yields mocha results only.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown, under "Scoping" -> "You can also group tests together using a describe block". "it" or "test" are equivalent. Never used mocha, not in my global installation either, in fact "npm list -g mocha" returns nothing.

Comment: True, my bad. What is the output of `console.log(settings)`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see it since the test gets stuck before that line, but probably undefined.

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough details. It's unclear how Config and the test are related. The class isn't in use anywhere. If there are promises involved and there's a timeout, it's safe to assume it's there for a good reason, i.e. there is really a timeout. What is Settings, is it Mongoose? It isn't mentioned in the question. There could be a problem with db connection that results in pending promise.

Answer (score 0):

Your Config class looks weird, it's importing `Settings` from `./settings.js` but it's not creating an instance of it or initialising it.

Without seeing all your code its difficult to see the context, but shouldn't your config class look like this:

```
const { Settings } = require("../models/settings");
const moment = require("moment");

class Config {

  async init() {
    const settingsTool = new Settings();
    await settingsTool.init();

    let settings = await settingsTool.findOne(); // This looks like the line where it gets stuck
    if (!settings) settings = await createDefaultConfig();

    this.lastBookableDay = settings.lastBookableDay;
    this.slotDuration = settings.slotDuration;
    this.interval = settings.interval;
    this.expireOffset = settings.expireOffset;
    this.cancelationNotice = settings.cancelationNotice;
    this.week = settings.week;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Settings` is a mongoose model, it doesn't get instantiated. (also, OP stated their code works fine, it's just the test that fails)

Comment: @ChrisG Look at the test he posted, he requires Settings from `settings.js`, then calls the constructor, then calls the init function. That it works outside of the unit test doesn't mean much, since there are plenty of chances for it to be mutated or replaced etc by the rest of the code we don't see.